# How to add image to user profile in stream.io nodejs?

Tags: getstream-io

I'm trying to add an image to my user profile using the below code but it doesn't appear to be working when I run my app. Does anyone know how to properly do this in Node?

```js
client.user('the-user-id').update({
  name: "Gwen",
  occupation: "Software Engineer",
  gender: "female",
  image: "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/1069159?s=400&u=43561f3ac9eda2d28a4fc154443b0ad34ebc5208&v=4"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, you have to have the profile image named "profileImage" like so:

client.user('the-user-id').update({ name: "Gwen Stafani", occupation: "Software Engineer", gender: "female", profileImage: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/415829/pexels-photo-415829.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"});

Comment: How were you able to know that `profileImage` is the attribute to be used? .. Are there any docs/reference for this part?